# How to display numbers using comma as a thousands separator?

Tags: numbering, formatting

I want numbers like 5.5 million to be displayed using a comma as a thousands separator as "5,500,000". Is there a way to do this automatically, without having to manually put commas?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I think the [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package has this sort of facility.

```
\num[group-separator={,}]{1234567890}
```

Should give you 1,234,567,890

Also you can use this as a package option like so: `\usepackage[group-separator={,}]{siunitx}`

Be warned, this doesn't seem to work with older versions  of `siunitx`

Comment: `[group-separator={,}]` also works as package option.

Comment: I've just realised this doesn't work for me. Maybe I have an old version of siunitx or xkeyval  `siunitx.sty    2009/09/21 v1.3a A comprehensive (SI) units package
 xkeyval.sty    2008/08/13 v2.6a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2008/08/13 v2.6a key=value parser (HA)`

Comment: Same here. I can't get any commas to appear even if I use group-separator as a package option. There is some problem with xkeyval. I am on Ubuntu Maverick and using its latest latex packages. Any ideas for fixes?

Comment: @donatello Are you sure you have v.2.1 of siunitx? The ubuntu TeX packages aren't that up to date... I'm on maverick too and the version of siuntix that ships with it is 1.3... You need to update by hand if you want to use this, I guess.

Comment: Can you please point me to a guide that shows how to install separate tex libraries by hand?

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Packages/Installing_Extra_Packages

Comment: With siunitx v1.3, try `[digitsep={,}]`.

Comment: Note also that in general giving options using `\sisetup` is a better approach than using the load-time options due to the issues with the LaTeX2e kernel and option expansion.

Comment: I can't even get `digitsep={,}` to work witihin `\sisetup`

Comment: @donatello. Along with the \usepackage line, in order to show the commas, I still had to wrap the number in a \num{} form. Are you doing this?

Comment: Also note that you need `group-minimum-digits={3}` if you want it to work for 4-digit numbers (e.g., `1000`), otherwise for me it only works for 5 or more digits.

Answer (score 8):

Seamus' answer involving `siunitx` is the Right Way<sup>TM</sup> to do this. That said, it's not so hard to write a simple macro to pretty-print numbers.

```
\newcount\ppnum
\newcommand\ppnumber[1]{%
        \ppnum=#1\relax
        \ifnum\ppnum<0
                $-$%
                \ppnum=-\ppnum
        \fi
        \let\pptemp\empty
        \loop\ifnum\ppnum>999
                \count255=\ppnum
                \divide\ppnum by1000
                \count255=\numexpr \count255 - 1000*\ppnum \relax
                \edef\pptemp{,\ifnum\count255<100 0\ifnum\count255<10 0\fi\fi
                             \the\count255 \pptemp}%
        \repeat
        \the\ppnum
        \pptemp
}
```

The first time I wrote this, I used a token register rather than `\pptemp`, but that required writing `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter...` which just seemed excessive.

**Edit:**
Given that I've now had to fix two bugs in my code, maybe I shouldn't have claimed that it isn't so hard to do this. =)

Comment: +1 for simple programming algorithms written in pure TeX. And apparently TeX doesn't have an \abs macro.

Comment: @Martin: Well, I did use the e-TeX primitive `\numexpr` because it was slightly shorter.

Comment: TH.  

Your Macro has a small problem: when the number is for example  1008110, as the number gets divided by 1000 the second time, the remainder is 8, and the result is printed as: 1,8,110 rather than 1,008,110.  I am trying to find a fix to this since this will happen for any number that has a remainder from the division from 0-99.

Leo

Comment: @Leo: You're absolutely right. Thank you for pointing this out. It required only a minor fix. Still, it shows why the right way to do it is to use `siunitx` rather than roll one's own.

Comment: @TH.: I wanted to add a comment, but those are only allowed to consist of about 600 characters, therefore I added another answer (see below).

Comment: Tried it w/`31556952000`, gives "number too big", likely due to processing the number mathematically instead of as text and 32-bit number processing. This comment is intended as a signpost, not a criticism.

Answer (score 5):

Using the http://www.ctan.org/pkg/numprint package with `\npthousandsep{,}` might be an alternative (found after writing the other answer - Murphy's Law!).

Btw: Grouping numbers into pairs of *two* can be done with the http://www.ctan.org/pkg/telprint package.

Answer (score 4):

[`sistyle`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/sistyle) can typeset a wide range of numbers with custom number separators, such as exponential numbers. For example, try:

```
% preamble
\usepackage{sistyle}
\SIthousandsep{,}

% document
\num{5500000} and \num{5.50e6} are equal.
```

5,500,000 and 5.50 × 10<sup>6</sup> are equal.

---

Note that `sistyle` is (in principle) superseded by `siunitx` (see [accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6105)); however, `sistyle` has maintenance-only support.

Comment: Can I ask how to make it work with numbers that are of length 4? For example `\num{1111}` doesn't work (wanted `1,111`).

Comment: @PoGibas good question. This decision is intentional for both `sistyle` and `siunitx`, but I'm not sure how to modify it. It could be a new question.

Answer (score 3):

I usually only use this once in my document and don't want to bother with some additional package, so I found the following to be a very useful trick:

```tex
$50{\small,}000$
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.stackexchange.com! The original poster asked for automatic ways of doing this, not manual. This is a manual solution.

Comment: It's still useful for other people who come here, at least for me :)

Answer (score 2):

The siunitx documentation, v2.3d, 2011/08/18, section 2 Installation, says:

> "The package requires LaTeX3 support as provided in the l3kernel and
>   l3packages bundles. [...] LaTeX3, and so siunitx, requires the e-TeX
>   extensions: these are available on all modern TEX systems."

Whenever siunitx/LaTeX3/e-TeX are not available (because one is stuck with something other than a modern TeX system), TH.'s \ppnumber is a great help, if

```
\count255=\numexpr \count255 - 1000*\ppnum \relax
```

is replaced by something like (there is no `\count254` temporary counter, this is just a pseudo-example!)

```
\count254 =\ppnum
\multiply\count254 by 1000
\advance\count255 by -\count254 \relax
```

. TH. said that he deliberately choose

> "e-TeX primitive `\numexpr` because it was slightly shorter"

, but for an alternative to siunitx (in regard of pretty printing numbers) I would suggest going for the most compatible code (even if longer). Additionally, I would suggest replacing

```
 $-$%
```

with

```
\ensuremath{-}%
```

because `\ppnumber` might be used in math mode (where the first `$` would *end* the math mode), and I would also suggest

replacing

```
\newcommand\ppnumber[1]{%
```

with

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\ppnumber}[1]{%
```

because one never knows whether the command will be used in a way, so that it can break.
Further I needed to place a `\def\pptemp{}` before `\newcommand\ppnumber` (or before `\DeclareRobustCommand{\ppnumber}`), otherwise I get a

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\ppnumber  ...t 253\relax \relax \fi \let \pptemp
```

As a last thought: `\@bsphack` `\@esphack` might be used (requiring `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, of course).
As a very last thought: Replacing `,` by `\thousandseparator` and adding

```
\def\thousandseparator{,}
%\def\thousandseparator{.}
%\def\thousandseparator{\,}
```

would make it clear that there is flexibility in choosing the separator. (There are languages where the comma is used instead of the period as decimal separator, for example.)

In summary, I got

```
\makeatletter

\def\thousandseparator{,}
%\def\thousandseparator{.}
%\def\thousandseparator{\,}

\def\pptemp{}
\def\ppnumbersign{}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\ppnumber}[1]{%
\@bsphack
\count255=#1\relax
\ifnum\count255 <0
\def\ppnumbersign{\ensuremath{-}}%
\count255=-\count255\relax
\else
\def\ppnumbersign{\empty}%
\fi
\let\pptemp\empty
\loop\ifnum\count255>999
\edef\ppnc{\the\count255}\relax
\divide\count255 by 1000
\edef\ppna{\the\count255}\relax
\multiply\count255 by 1000
\advance\count255 by -\ppnc
\count255=-\count255\relax
\edef\pptemp{\thousandseparator
\ifnum\count255<100 0
  \ifnum\count255<10 0
  \fi
\fi
\the\count255\pptemp
}%
\count255=\ppna
\repeat
\@esphack%
\ppnumbersign\ppna\pptemp\relax%
}

\makeatother
```

About `count` and `counter`:

http://www.texdev.net/2009/11/17/tex-counts-and-latex-counters/.

Comment: Spaces (and newlines) are ignored after control words (e.g., `\relax`, `\empty`, `\pptemp`, `\fi`). The comments following those can thus be removed. Note that `\count255` is a temporary (by convention only), but `\count254` is not. You should probably use `\newcount` if you want to use others. I don't understand why you have `\relax\relax` in a bunch of places. Numbers can be followed by an optional space token so, for example, `\count255=\count253` followed by a newline is sufficient. (In fact, the `=` is optional too.)

Comment: @TH.: >"Note that \count255 is a temporary (by convention only), but \count254 is not." Ups! Did not know that, thanks for the information. I changed the code accordingly.