# How to correctly write the thousands separator in American English?

Tags: formatting, english, number

I am not a native speaker and I must write a scientific document in American English. How would you correctly write "10000" using LaTeX ?

1. with a space only (10 000): `$10\,000$`
2. with a coma and no space in either side (10,000): `$10{,}000$`
3. with a coma and a space on its right (10, 000) : `$10,000$`

I have seen the second a few times, but I do not know if there is a consensus. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would recommend that you use the `siunitx` package and then `\num{10000}`. That way you can always change it later. Without `siunitx`, I would use the first option your suggest: `$10\,000$`

Comment: you can use `numprint` package with option `autolanguage` (assuming you use babel with `american` or `USenglish` class option)

Comment: @PeterGrill thanks a lot, I think I will go on with this for now. Could you propose it as an answer so I can accept it ?

Comment: For the record, as an American, the thin space is well-known and understood in technical fields, but almost unheard-of in the general population. (No idea about business contexts). I would guess that the thin space would be understood even by those who had never seen it before in most contexts, though, especially if the context made it clear that a single number was expected (particularly one of that magnitude). The comma is vastly more common, even in technical fields, and ubiquitous in the general population. There is never a space after the comma used as a separator.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My recommendation would be to use `siunitx`'s  `\num{}` macro (which by default will add a `\thinspace`, but can be configured to add a comma if so desired):

[image]

### References:

- [How to display numbers using comma as a thousands separator?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6104/4301).
- [How to set the precision in numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59006/4301).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\num{10000}: Recommended (Using \verb|\num{}|)

$10\,000$: Manual Spacing

\sisetup{group-separator={,}}
\num{10000}: In case you decide you want the comma

\end{document}
```