# Using a footnote multiple times in tabular* environment with desired symbols

Tags: tables, footnotes

I have the following table, which I still keep filling. I would like to add footnotes to several places. For instance, for rows 2 (207.09) and 3 (300.00) of the Nonlinear column, I want to add the same footnote (say note1), and for rows 4 (600.00) and 5 (600.00) of the same column, I want another footnote (say note2). Also, I would prefer customizable footnote symbols like *, +, etc.

I tried several methods that were readily given as answers. Some solutions include threeparttable and scrextend packages. I also tried others, but they did not work (got errors) probably because of tabular*.

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,enumitem,nccmath}
\usepackage{graphicx,geometry,tabularx,tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs,mathtools,multirow,relsize,subfig,mwe}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\begin{table}
    \caption{Solution statistics for computational experiments.}\label[tab]{comp_res}
    {\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{c @{\extracolsep{\fill}} cccccccc}
    \toprule 
    \multirow{2}{*}{$|\setI|$} & \multirow{2}{*}{$|\setK|$} & \multirow{2}{*}{Instances} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Average Gap}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Average Time (s)} \\ \cline{4-9}
    & & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Cut} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{User cut} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Nonlinear} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Cut} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{User cut} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Nonlinear} \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{6}{*}{40} & 5 & 50 & $3.7\times 10^{-5}$ & $2.0\times 10^{-5}$ & $3.4\times 10^{-5}$ & 15.06 & 14.04 & 23.87 \\
    & 10 & 25 & $8.8\times 10^{-5}$ & $5.9\times 10^{-5}$ & $2.5\times 10^{-2}$ & 19.10 & 26.04 & 207.09 \\
    & 15 & 10 & $9.4\times 10^{-5}$ & $6.5\times 10^{-5}$ & $7.6\times 10^{-2}$ & 28.35 & 74.89 & 300.00 \\
    & 20 & 5 & $1.1\times 10^{-4}$ & $2.2\times 10^{-5}$ & $11.9\times 10^{-2}$ & 112.9 & 464.6 & 600.00 \\
    & 25 & 5 & $2.2\times 10^{-4}$ & $9.1\times 10^{-5}$ & $11.2\times 10^{-2}$ & 123.7 & 314.6 & 600.00 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want  table  notes (after the last row) or standard footnotes (at the bottom of the page)?

Comment: It was after the last row.

Comment: The solution was  given by @leandriis, with threeparttable, as long as the table does not have to break across pages.

Comment: Well, it does not. But, I (future I and others) would be interested in seeing your solution method as well.

Comment: It would be strictly the same. Only in the case of a longtable, there would be some differences, because threparttable doesn't work in this case, and has to be replaces with `threeparttablex`  and its `ThreePartTable` & `TableNotes` environments, which use a slightly different syntax.

Comment: This table will fit to one page. But, this is good to know, in case I or someone else needs it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following example, I have used `\tnote` and the `tablenotes` environment for the table notes, added `siunitx` in order to improve the input and alignment of numbers in the table, replaced the `\cline` command with two `\cmidrule` commands in order to improve the visual separation between the two blocks of three columns.

In addition, I removed the optional argument of the `\label` command since this caused "tab]{comp_res}" to be printed above the table in the resulting pdf file. I also placed the `hyperref` package at the end of the preamble since this package should (with a few exceptions) be the lat package you load. Lastly, I also had to replace `\setK` and `\setI` since the definitions of there commands was not given in the original example code.

[image]

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,enumitem,nccmath}
\usepackage{graphicx,geometry,tabularx,tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs,mathtools,multirow,relsize,subfig,mwe}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} % Should be the last package in the preamble (with a few exceptions)

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Solution statistics for computational experiments.}\label[tabl]{compres}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{c @{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
                                 c
                                 S[table-format=2]
                                 S[table-format=1.1e-1]
                                 S[table-format=1.1e-1]
                                 S[table-format=2.1e-1]
                                 S[table-format=3.2]
                                 S[table-format=3.2]
                                 S[table-format=3.2,table-space-text-post=\tnote{+}]
                                 }
    \toprule 
    \multirow{2}{*}{$|I|$} 
      & \multirow{2}{*}{$|K|$} 
        & {\multirow{2}{*}{Instances}} 
          & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Average Gap} 
             & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Average Time (s)} \\ 
     \cmidrule(r){4-6} \cmidrule(l){7-9}
      & & 
        & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Cut} 
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{User cut} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Nonlinear} 
              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Cut} 
                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{User cut} 
                  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Nonlinear} \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{5}{*}{40} & 5  & 50 & 3.7 E-5 & 2.0 E-5 &  3.4 E-5 & 15.06 & 14.04 & 23.87 \\
                        & 10 & 25 & 8.8 E-5 & 5.9 E-5 &  2.5 E-2 & 19.10 & 26.04 & 207.09\tnote{*} \\
                        & 15 & 10 & 9.4 E-5 & 6.5 E-5 &  7.6 E-2 & 28.35 & 74.89 & 300.00\tnote{*} \\
                        & 20 & 5  & 1.1 E-4 & 2.2 E-5 & 11.9 E-2 & 112.9 & 464.6 & 600.00\tnote{+} \\
                        & 25 & 5  & 2.2 E-4 & 9.1 E-5 & 11.2 E-2 & 123.7 & 314.6 & 600.00\tnote{+} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
    \begin{tablenotes}
    \item[*] text 
    \item[+] other text
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I really appreciate for your time. Only one issue is remaining. When I add the following row & 50 & 5 & 2.8 E-4 & 2.8 E-2 & 5.8 E-2 & 1236.0 & 3600.0 & 3600.0 \\ and try to use comma separators for 1236 and 3600s, an error shows up. To fix it, I tried this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6104/how-to-display-numbers-using-comma-as-a-thousands-separator but got other errors. Can you also help for that?

Comment: Nvm, this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55882681/ho-to-set-numbers-with-commas-in-table-latex) solved that issue. Thanks a lot!